# MPDF font family not working

Tags: css, pdf, mpdf

I am working with MPDF library. Everything is done except the font family is not being implemented. Can anyone tell me how should I do this? I tried `@font-face{}` but it is not working. Please guide me. Note: I am working with Urdu font.

Here is the css code

```
 @font-face {
        font-family:  nastalique;
        src: url(fajer-noori-nastalique-regular-1.ttf);
        -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
        -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family:  nastalique;
        src: url(fonts/fajer-noori-nastalique-regular-1.ttf);
    }
```

Here Is PHP code i am using in config_fonts.php

```
$this->fontdata = array(
    "dejavusanscondensed" => array(
        'R' => "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf",
        'B' => "DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf",
        'I' => "DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf",
        'BI' => "DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
        'useKashida' => 75,
        ),
    "noori_nastalique" => array(
        'R' => "fajer-noori-nastalique-regular-1.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
        'useKashida' => 75,
    ),
)
```

And Here is my html code

```
<td width="300" align="center" class="font" style="font-family: noori_nastalique"
!important;">
```

Thanks

Comment: You're defining your font-face as 'nastalique', so why are you trying to use 'dejavusans' in your HTML?

Comment: @SeanCogan i tried with nastlique but same problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

MPDF or TCPDF both are mostly used for HTML 2 PDF conversion.

They support all LTR languages but Unfortunately, They doesn't support all RTL language.

There is support available for some RTL languages like Persian or Arabic, but not urdu language. Your above code will work for Above languages, But not for URDU.